# Get process ID from command line in a 32 bits environment

Tags: powershell

In order to kill a task if a cancellation of this one is needed, I have to find the `ProcessID` of the process started by my application.

I've found a command line that works fine in 64 bit environment, I give it the command line use to launch the process and it gives me the `ProcessID` as I wanted:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "commandLine = 'command line of the process'" | Select ProcessId | findstr /R /C:"[0 - 9]" | % TrimStart
```

`findstr` & `Trimstart` are used to get only the `ProcessID` and not the entire line or the entire return of the function.

But when I try the same command on a 32 bit window, the result is empty.

I first thought the command line wasn't compatible with a 32 bits environment but it seems more that not every command line is stocked on a 32 bit environment.

When I try to print every command line of every process started, I have a lot of white lines that I haven't on the 64 bits environment.

Is there another way to accomplish the same thing on a 32 bits environment ?

Comment: Have you considered using the `Get-Process` CmdLet?

Comment: I didn't find anything about using it to find a process id from a command Line, could you confirm ?

Comment: It looks to be a powershell issue rather than your code as I get the same behaviour (it works with powershell but not powershell x86) with: `Get-Process | Where-Object Path -EQ "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id`

Comment: i was able to get the same query working in 64 bit and 32 bit  (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process|where-object{$_.commandline -eq 'comandLine'}).processid